# Interpreting linear and quadratic terms with same sign

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression, polynomial, quadratic-form

I am running a second order model with betweenness centrality and closeness centrality as independent variables and cognitive demand as dependent variable.

The results shows that betweenness centrality is not significant as a linear variable but is positive and betweenness centrality^2 is positive and significant.
Closeness centrality is negative and significant both as linear and quadratic term

How do I interpret these results? Please help

Comment: Welcome to CV.  First, it would help if you give the actual output (either cut and paste or listing the parameter estimates).  Second, I'm worried about collinearity and, even if it isn't technically problematic, what the meaning of either IV in the model is when you control for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your model fits your data well and passes all the residual tests, this result simply means the relationship (between your x and y) is not linear. You might consider the following questions:

1. what's the feasible domain of my x?
2. take a closer look at the coefficients of your x and x^2 and see how they impact your y in the feasible domain

p.s. if you do a little math and you can combine your x and x^2 into (x-a)^2 + b which might be easier for interpretation.  for example, the re distance to center of mass vs gravity force.